# My contact form 7 doesn't appear on my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I always used this contact form with its shortcode, but now it doesn't appear anymore.

I try in all the pages but it doesn't appear, I tried with other form plugins and they worked, but I have to use contact form 7. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the new editor or the classic one? As I think with Gutenberg you need to use a shortcode block or a Contact Form 7 form block (if there is one).

Comment: I am using the shortcode block of elementor